# What's the correct type hint for a metaclass method in Python that returns a class instance?

Tags: python, type-hinting, metaclass

In the example below, `__getitem__` indicates the class type as a hint, rather than return of a `SpecialClass` object.

```py
from typing import Self

class SpecialMeta(type):
    def __getitem__(cls, key) -> Self:
        ...

class SpecialClass(metaclass=SpecialMeta):
    ...

one = SpecialClass()
# type(one) : SpecialClass

two = SpecialClass["findme"]
# type(two) : type[SpecialClass]
```

What is the correct type hint to indicate `type(two) = SpecialClass` instead of `type[SpecialClass]`?  Is there a general way to do this starting around Python 3.8 or so?

Comment: The example you've provided only works in Python 3.11 (which is when `Self` was introduced). Are you asking whether there's an analogous way to do the same in prior versions of Python? Or are you asking how to get the `SpecialClass` result instead of the `type[SpecialClass]` result that works in 3.11 and possibly earlier versions?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion...  I'm trying to accomplish the latter: get the type hint to result in `SpecialClass` rather than `type[SpecialClass]`.

Comment: `def __getitem__(cls: type[_T], key: str) -> _T:` ([playground link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=f044cfccfe023c842e640569df1cd07a))?

Comment: @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike - that seems to do the trick!  do you want to write up the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment by "@_SUTerliakov - supports strike",
this can be done with generics by simply indicating that the generic
type goes in, and an instance of it comes out:

```
import typing

T_ = typing.Generic()

def __getitem__(cls: type[_T], key: str) -> _T:
    ...
    instance = cls(...)
    ...
    return instance
```